# Having trouble displaying results from a database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've annotated my code with the problem, any suggestions on solving this?  Been stuck on it for a couple of hours now..

```
<?php
include("header.php");
$inv = mysql_query("SELECT `item_id` FROM `user_items` WHERE `user_id`='".$_SESSION['uid']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$linv = mysql_fetch_array($inv);

//Need to display all item_id's from the user_items table where the user_id field = $_SESSION['uid'] (or 1 for testing purposes.)
//For some reason, every foreach and while loop method i have tried is giing me false data (1,1).  The right data should be: 1, 4.
//The database table contains 3 columns: slot_id, user_id, item_id.
//Those columns contain the following data: 1       1          1
//                                          2       2          4
//                                          3       1          4
//surely this should return $linv as an array containing the values 1 and 4?  What's going on?


}
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: is this query running? because i am unable to see db connection object in picture. also stop using `mysql_*`, they are deprecated. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: have you tried running the constructed query in MySQL server manually?

Comment: Updated code:  echoing "1 1". :

<?php
include("header.php");
$inv = mysql_query("SELECT `item_id` FROM `user_items` WHERE `user_id`='".$_SESSION['uid']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$linv = mysql_fetch_array($inv);

while(list($key, $value) = each($linv)){
    echo($value);
}

Comment: When i run the query directly on the sql prompt or in phpymyadmin it returns the two fields i want.  I think its just a problem with the way I am presenting the data from the mysql_fetch_assoc.  And i know its depreciated, but its the only one i know how to use.

Comment: PHP MySQL PDO class, you could try use it and see if you like it https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class

Comment: It looks like your code is missing a loop "while" See some examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($inv, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { print $row['item_id']; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```html
$linv = mysql_fetch_array($inv); 
while(list($key, $value) = each($linv))
{ 
    echo($value); 
}
```

to

```html
while($linv = mysql_fetch_array($inv))
{
    echo $linv['item_id'] . ' ';
}
```

**Edit: problem reason**
- The first problem is that `$linv = mysql_fetch_array` returns only the next row and stores it as an array in `$linv`, in the very beginning it starts with row # 0
So the first problem is that you were missing a loop to retrieve all rows
- Now you may ask your self "If I'm getting only one row so why the output was 1 1", this is because `mysql_fetch_array` accepts a second parameter which detriments the fetch mode (MYSQL_ASSOC for associative array which can be accessed only with columns names in the query, MYSQL_NUMERIC for numeric array which can be accessed only with numbers 0,1,2 ... in the same order columns are specified in the select clause), when you don't pass that parameter, then MYSQL_BOTH will be used by default and you will get the first row like that ["0" => "1" , "item_id" => "1"] 
What you were doing is just looping through all the elements in the first row

Comment: Thanks that worked!  Can you please explain why? / What i was doing wrong?

Comment: o.k I will update the answer with details of the problem